# Writing a generic class that is not a container? [C#]

Tags: c#, generics, comparison, operator-overloading, operators

**Goal:**

I've been trying to write a generic helper/utility class in C# that represents a bounds-checked range of numbers.

The idea is that the user can create a contiguous range of numbers by defining a minimum and maximum value (for example, from 0 to 10, from -15 to 3, from -7 to -2, etc.). The range also contains a current value, and the value is checked against the upper/lower limits. If the current value is large than the max (or lower than the min) it is either capped or wraps around. I want this class to be generic so that the client can select the appropriate type/size/precision for their use-case.

Here's what I have so far:

```
public class Range<T> where T : IComparable<T> {

    private T value;
    private T min;
    private T max;

    private bool wrap;

    public Range ( T minimumValue, T maximumValue, T initialValue, bool tempWrap = false ) {
        value = initialValue;
        min = minimumValue;
        max = maximumValue;
        wrap = tempWrap;

        LimitBounds ();
    }

    private void LimitBounds () {
        if( wrap != true ) {
            if ( value > max ) { value = max; }
            else if ( value < min ) { value = min ; }
        }
        else {
            T wrapAmount = 0;

            if ( value > max ) { 
                wrapAmount = value - max;
                value = min + wrapAmount;
            }
            else if ( value < min ) {
                wrapAmount = min - value;
                value = max - wrapAmount;
            }
        }
    }

    public T GetValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void SetValue(T tempValue) {
        value = tempValue;
        LimitBounds ();
    }

    public void Increment() {
        value++;
        LimitBounds ();
    }

    public void Decrement() {
        value--;
        LimitBounds ();
    }

    public bool Equals(Range<T> tempRange)
    {
        return (value == tempRange.value);
    }

    public static bool operator > (Range<T> r1, Range<T> r2)
    {
        return (r1.value > r2.value);
    }

    public static bool operator < (Range<T> r1, Range<T> r2)
    {
        return (r1.value < r2.value);
    }

    public static Range<T> operator ++ ( Range<T> r ) {
        r.Increment ();
        return r;
    }

    public static Range<T> operator -- ( Range<T> r ) {
        r.Decrement ();
        return r;
    }
}
```

**Problem:**

I'm really new to C# and despite having a bit more C++ experience, I'm kind of stuck here. My compiler is complaining:

```
"Operator `>' cannot be applied to operands of type `T' and `T'"
```

.. It's got similar errors about most of my operator overloads. I thought that if I made sure that the types that my class deals with implement 'Comparable' it would be OK to overload the comparison operators. I'm clearly doing something wrong here, but I'm not sure what I need to do.

If it simplifies things, this class really only needs to deal with purely numeric values/types (byte,short,int,float,etc.)..

**Update Edit 1:**

As suggested below, I was able to eliminate a bunch of compile errors cause by comparison operations by switching to the CompareTo in these functions:

```
    public bool Equals(Range<T> tempRange)
    {
        return (value.CompareTo(tempRange.value) == 0);
    }

    public static bool operator > (Range<T> r1, Range<T> r2)
    {
        return (r1.value.CompareTo (r2.value) > 0);
    }

    public static bool operator < (Range<T> r1, Range<T> r2)
    {
        return (r1.value.CompareTo (r2.value) < 0);
    }
```

I also added the 'struct' constraint. I'm still unsure of where to go from here, though. My code *still wont compile due to the various addition, subtraction, increment, and decrement operators that I've been using*. I've tried to add byte, short, int, and float as additional type constraints, but that didn't work and it gave me a compile-time error.

What options do I have from here? Because this class is only meant to deal with ranges of numbers (basically only integers of various sizes [byte, short, int, long maybe] and floating-point decimals) and not nullable or reference types, is there some other constraint that I can use to make this work? Do I have to make a bunch of wrapper classes around the basic data types that implement a custom 'INumber' interface?

Or is this a misuse of generic classes, and I should just make a bunch of stand-alone range classes for the different types? Is it possible to make a generic class that implements the type of behavior that I want?

Comment: Operators are not virtual and thus can never be used with generic types as so. Use the applicable methods defined for the constrained type. Remember that generics are *not* templates and there is no "textual substitution" that occurs. Thus the code has to be type-valid for *all* types representable by `T` within the generic class itself.

Comment: How are you going to do `value++` and `value--` in the methods `Increment` and `Decrement` when you do not know the type?

Comment: Duh! I see.. Thanks guys. Originally I was writing this class with 'Short's, but after I got that working I decided that it would be more useful/flexible to make it more generic. I considered making a few classes like 'IntRange', 'ShortRange', 'FloatRange', etc. I think this will be a lot better when I figure it out. I've used other people's generics before, but this is my first shot at writing one. :]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason of the error is compiler can't be sure that the type of `T` will overload all those operators properly.And also there is no such constraint to force it.

Instead of comparison operators use `CompareTo` method for example, instead of

```
value > max
```

Use

```
value.CompareTo(max) > 0
```

For equality `value.CompareTo(max) == 0` for less than: `value.CompareTo(max) < 0`

For more information have a look at the documentation [`IComparable.CompareTo Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.compareto(v=vs.110).aspx)

`Increment` and `Decrement` operators are more tricky. You can write different *overloads* for your types to increment and decrement, and call the appropriate overload for the current type.

And a last note if you are planning to use this method with only struct types like (byte,int,double) you might want to add a `struct` constraint.

Comment: I think `value.CompareTo(max) > 1` should be `> 0`.

Comment: Of course it could blow up if `T` were a reference type and `value` were a null reference. Another soulution is `if (Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(value, max) > 0) { ... }`. If, on the other hand, you know you will not use this with reference types, you can give the constriant as `where T : struct, IComparable<T>`. Regarding equality, consider if `Equals` is not the method you want. If you constrain to `IEquatable<T>` you will avoid boxing and type-check in some cases (although those are very fast).

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. After adding constraints and switching to CompareTo where applicable I've managed to get the generic comparisons to work! Unfortunately, I still have a bunch of addition, subtractions, increment, and decrement operations that are throwing compile errors.. I've also added a struct constraint. Is there a different generic constraint that I can use to help get +, -, ++, and -- working?

Comment: Or is it not possible/advisable to try to use generics for this kind of thing? Should I give up and just make a few specific Range classes? (ByteRange, IntRange, FloatRange, etc.) .. Or would using specific constraints for each type that I want this class to handle work? (Byte, Short, Int, Float, Double, etc. as constraints)..

Comment: @Selman22 If you have time, can you elaborate a bit on what you said about writing "different overloads" for each type for the Increment/Decrement functions? How can I have overloads for each type when these functions have no parameters?

Comment: @MrKatSwordfish they should have parameters. like `void Increment(ref int i)` and you need to check typeof T and pass it to appropriate function

Answer (score 1):

This is the issue of using operators and generics so much of that code won't compile.  For example, `value++` or `value--`.  The compiler doesn't know if `T` implements specific operators.  Unfortunately there's no constraint for operators (yet), so you're left with some pretty non-generic solutions or you can use `dynamic` as a work-around.

**Please note** this is bypassing compile time checks.  Your code can compile just fine with types that will break at runtime.

```
public void Increment()
{
    dynamic x = value;
    x++;
    value = x;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. If possible I'd like to avoid this; it just seems like a good idea to minimize the risk of runtime errors where possible. I'd much rather have my code fail at compile time than crash unexpectedly down the line! :] I'm finding this a lot more difficult than I thought it would be.. haha

Comment: @MrKatSwordfish Understood.  When I've done this in projects I've used a `struct` constraint along with clear comments to minimize the chance of misuse.

Answer (score 0):

With generics, you cannot do arithmetic operations, as till the compile time, you do not know the type of .

So there are two things you can do:

1. If it is always, that you will be having either of long, decimal etc types, then restrict your generic class only for these types.
2. Operator overloading

Comment: "Can do .. operator overloading"?